# How to test performance of MySQL NDB cluster(NDB storage engine) using SYSBENCH?

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster, sysbench

- I want to test the performance of my **NDB cluster**.
- I am thinking of using **sysbench**.
- Are there any particular configuration changes required to make it work with the **NDB cluster**?
- Is there any flag that I need to use during runtime to mention the Storage engine explicitly.

Need some help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--mysql_storage_engine=ndbcluster flag while running sysbench command worked for me testing NDB cluster-specific performance.

Answer (score 2):

I have a set of scripts that I use to automate benchmarking with NDB Cluster.
They are available from the MySQL website and contains both the scripts to
automate Sysbench execution and a sysbench version integrated with those
scripts.

This blog provides a manual into how to use those scripts.
http://mikaelronstrom.blogspot.com/2018/08/manual-for-benchmark-toolset-dbt2.html

The script run_oltp.sh contains the setup of the execution of the sysbench
program if you want to use sysbench on your own.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Mikael. I guess --mysql_storage_engine=ndbcluster (sysbench) would work in my case. I can use this flag while preparing tables and finally running the traffic.